# Is there a code in python to highlight certain words (not code syntax) in a Microsoft Word document?

Tags: python, ms-word

I am new to Python and am creating a code to search for and highlight abstract nouns in a Word document. I have successfully programmed it to find all of the abstract nouns in a .txt document but cannot find a code to highlight the words in its .docx format. The only results I can find in my research are to highlight code syntax, or the code in relevant search results outputs errors in the program. For example, anything with add_run returns the error that there is no attribute.

This is my current working code:

```
import re
import os

source = open('title.txt')
text = source.read()

ment = re.findall(r'\w*ment+\w*', text)
ity = re.findall(r'\w*ity+\w*', text)
tion = re.findall(r'\w*tion+\w*', text)
age = re.findall(r'\w*age+\w*', text)
ance = re.findall(r'\w*ance+\w*', text)
ence = re.findall(r'\w*ence+\w*', text)
dom = re.findall(r'\w*dom+\w*', text)
ery = re.findall(r'\w*ery+\w*', text)
ry = re.findall(r'\w*ry+\w*', text)
ism = re.findall(r'\w*ism+\w*', text)
ness = re.findall(r'\w*ness+\w*', text)
hood = re.findall(r'\w*hood+\w*', text)

nominalizations = ment, ity, tion, age, ance, ence, dom, ery, ry, hood, ism, 
ness

import docx
from docx import Document
from docx.text.run import Font
from docx.text.run import Run
from docx.enum.text import WD_COLOR_INDEX

doc = docx.Document('title.docx")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're use python-docx library? Maybe you need read documentation http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html#paragraph-objects

IMHO simplest way use Word as COM object. For example:

```
msword = win32com.client.Dispatch('Word.Application')
msword.Visible = 0
path = "C:\\temp\\"

try:
    files = os.listdir(path)
    emailfile = open(os.path.join(path, 'emaillist.txt'), 'w')
    compreg = re.compile('([\w\-\.]+@(\w[\w\-]+\.)+[\w\-]+)', re.IGNORECASE)
    for i in range(0, len(files)):
        filename = os.path.join(path, files[i])
        doc = msword.Documents.Open(filename)
       emails = re.findall(p, doc.Content.Text)
       if emails:
            for email in emails: 
                emailfile.write(email)
                emailfile.write()
       print ("[%d] %s DONE" % (i, filename))
       doc = msword.Documents.Close()
except ...
    # process all exceptions here
finally:
    msword.Quit()
```